# what will be the time complexity for below checking whether a point lies inside a polygon or not ? is it O(n) or something else?

Tags: time-complexity

As there are n number of vertices in a given polygon , so is there possibility of time complexity O(n)? 
I think as because here no for loop is used. Only If and nested If conditions are checked for n vertices of polygons, so it will be O(n)?
Is my explanation correct?
or it will be something else complexity? I have confusion to calculate this program's complexity. 
Can anyone please explain me the calculation of time complexity step by step for this program only?

```
        static boolean onSegment(Point p, Point q, Point r)  
           { 
        if (q.x <= Math.max(p.x, r.x) && 
            q.x >= Math.min(p.x, r.x) && 
            q.y <= Math.max(p.y, r.y) && 
            q.y >= Math.min(p.y, r.y)) 
             { 
            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
static int orientation(Point p, Point q, Point r)  
    int val = (q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x) 
            - (q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y); 
    if (val == 0)   
        return 0; // colinear  
    return (val > 0) ? 1 : 2; // clock or counterclock wise  
       static boolean doIntersect(Point p1, Point q1,  
                Point p2, Point q2) 
    int o1 = orientation(p1, q1, p2); 
     if (o1 != o2 && o3 != o4) 
      return true;  
     if (o1 == 0 && onSegment(p1, p2, q1))  
         return true; 
     do 
       { 
           int next = (i + 1) % n; 
              if (doIntersect(polygon[i], polygon[next], p, extreme))  
        { 
            if (orientation(polygon[i], p, polygon[next]) == 0) 
            { 
                return onSegment(polygon[i], p, 
                                 polygon[next]); 
            } 
 public static void main(String[] args)  
    { 
        Point polygon1[] = {new Point(10,50), 
                            new Point(90,20),  
                            new Point(200,20),  
                            new Point(270,50),
                            new Point(200,130),
                            new Point(90,130)};
        int n = polygon1.length; 

        Point p = new Point(120,10);

        if (isInside(polygon1, n, p)) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Point 120,10 of polygon2 is inside Polygon1"); 
        }  
        else 
        { 
            System.out.println("Point 120,10 of polygon2 is outside of polygon1 "); 
        }
```

Comment: Maybe start formatting your code. If you pasted it with TABs, tryt oexpand the TABs into SPCs first.

Comment: I have not pasted the full code here. I have kept some main loops and conditions . I just need the time complexity calculation. For clear understanding i pasted some part of the code here. Please tell me the time complexity. It is very much necessary to know this complexity .

Comment: Then I suggest formatting the code so it is readable. If getting an answer is important then make your question as answerable as you can.

Comment: i mean, you need to post the definition of "isInside(...)" and the full definition of orientation(...) which is chopped off in the above